# Como mostrar solo alguos datos de objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, array, variables

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    // ARREGLO
producto = [
    { n: 'Jabon en Pasta', az: 1, ro: 0, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'sol', grupo: 'No Incluidas' },
    { n: 'Ambientador', az: 2, ro: 1, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'Incluidas' },
    { n: 'Cloro', az: 2, ro: 0, am: 1, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'No Incluidas' }, 
    { n: 'Desinfectante', az: 2, ro: 1, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'Incluidas' } ];
```

Deseo obtener un listado separado de productos del grupo Incluidos y No Incluidos
He intentado con algo como:

```
ncompoa = "<h1>Formulas Incluidas</h1><ol>";
     for (li in producto) {
         ncompoa += "<li>";
         if (producto.grupo = 'Incluidas') {
             ncompoa +=  producto[li].n;
         }
        ncompoa += "</li>";
        };
        ncompoa += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = ncompoa;
```

Pero el resultado obtenido es completo de todos los productos los incluidos y los no incluidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto que intentas consultar en un arrayObjet, para lo cual tendrás que consultar primero por su posición [i] luego su propiedad.

También encontré este error en  if (producto.grupo = 'Incluidas'), al parecer se te olvido un = lo correcto es if (producto.grupo == 'Incluidas'). Espero te Ayude

```js
producto = [
    { n: 'Jabon en Pasta', az: 1, ro: 0, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'sol', grupo: 'No Incluidas' },
    { n: 'Ambientador', az: 2, ro: 1, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'Incluidas' },
    { n: 'Cloro', az: 2, ro: 0, am: 1, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'No Incluidas' }, 
    { n: 'Desinfectante', az: 2, ro: 1, am: 0, bla: 0, c: ' ', v: 0, t: 'liq', grupo: 'Incluidas' } ];
    
     ncompoa = "<h1>Formulas Incluidas</h1><ol>";
     ncompoa2 = "<h1>Formulas No Incluidas</h1><ol>";
     for (li in producto) {         
         if (producto[li].grupo == "Incluidas") {
          ncompoa += "<li>";
            ncompoa +=  producto[li].n;
            ncompoa += "</li>";
         }
         else{
          ncompoa2 += "<li>";
            ncompoa2 +=  producto[li].n;
            ncompoa2 += "</li>";
         } 
     }
     ncompoa += "</ol>";
     ncompoa2 += "</ol>";
     document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = ncompoa;
     document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = ncompoa2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="contenido"></p>
<p id="contenido2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```